# Deploying two applications on the same instance with clustering

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy two applications listening on different ports on the same instance (a `Next.js` application along with a `Node.js` API server). I will use a reverse proxy to route traffic to them accordingly.

The `Node.js` API server uses Node's native cluster module to cluster the application using all available cpu's. My question is, is it safe to first start the `Node.js` API server and let it cluster using all cpu's and then to start the `Next.js` application? Or will I have to reserve one (or multiple) cpu's for the `Next.js` application?

Thanks!